# How to prevent Google chrome from suppressing confirm() dialog

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, confirm

the new version from google chrome does not allow confirm dialog if the window is not active.
I have a page which is calling a popup. The popup has a button. on click of that button, a javascript function of parent page will be called . the javascript function has a confirm dialog.

after chrome update to Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build), this is not working any more with following warning.

"A window.confirm() dialog generated by this page was suppressed because this page is not the active tab of the front window. Please make sure your dialogs are triggered by user interactions to avoid this situation. https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5140698722467840"

try this [jsfiddle]: https://jsfiddle.net/VikasUpadhyay/47vurfm0/6/

Comment: What you can do is make sure your dialogs are triggered by user interactions to avoid this situation

Comment: Dialog is result of a user interaction (button click). but the button click is on popup and dialog is on parent page.

Comment: rather than using old school confirm/alert/prompt how about using something that shows a "modal" but non-blocking  dialogue - there's many to choose from